# How to create a loop if contents of a list is in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I'm asking the user for a name, and if that name contains a number I want to print that they need to remove the numbers. But I can't exit the loop afterwards.

```
    numbers=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
    vad2=input("To what site are you going to use the password? ")
    for f in numbers:
        if f in vad2:
            while True:
                print("You can't include numbers in the name of the site.")
                vad2=input("To what site are you going to use the password? ")
                numbers=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
                for f in numbers:
                    if f in vad2
                        print()
                    else:
                        break;
```

The first time I use:

```
for f in numbers:
   if f in vad2:
```

It works (the code skips the loop if I don't include any numbers) but when I do the same thing in the loop it wont work for some reason.

Comment: what's your input? replace "input" by a fixed string to create a [mcve]. You probably mixed strings & lists

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem is that I need to check the users input because they can't include numbers in the input. So I can't replace the input with a fixed string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break will jump over your 'for loop', not over your 'while loop'.
Modify your code like

```
if not vad2.isalpha():   # if you want only alphabet from your input
    print()
```